# Printing Open Ended Responses in knitr

Tags: r, knitr

I have survey data with a few questions that have "Other" as an option and respondents can enter a small amount of text. I'd like to set up a report using knitr where the open responses are printed automatically. When I use the `print` function every line appears like this:

```
## 1 This is an open ended response
## 2 Here is another response
## 3 I LOVE Stackoverflow, everyone is so helpful
## 4 knitr can be a real pain!
```

I've tried using gridTable but there doesn't seem to be an option to control the number of columns. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Some sample code showing how I've structured the data:

```
library(dplyr)

x <- c("Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female")
y <- c(NA, NA, "This is an open ended response", NA, "Here is another response", "I LOVE Stackoverflow, everyone is so helpful", "knitr can be a real pain!")

z <- data.frame (x,y, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

openResponse <- select (z, y) %>%
  filter (y != "NA")

print (openResponse)
```

I've also tried `\Sexpr{openResponse}` in knitr however it come out as a continuous string. I'd like to have it on separate line.

Comment: how do you want it to look? does `cat(na.omit(y), sep = '\n')` give you what you want? or `strwrap(na.omit(y))`

Comment: @rawr - `cat(na.omit(y), sep = '\n')` is better but it still prints the ## at the beginning of each line.

Comment: To get rdi of the `##` use `comment=NA` in the code chunk definition, as in ```{r comment=NA}

Comment: Thanks @jlhoward. It's still not ideal but workable. I changed with the code chunk definition to `results = asis` - looks better but no line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?? This knitr chunk:

````
```{r comment=NA, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
library(dplyr)
x <- c("Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female")
y <- c(NA, NA, "This is an open ended response", NA, 
       "Here is another response", "I LOVE Stackoverflow, everyone is so helpful", 
       "knitr can be a real pain!")
z <- data.frame (x,y, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
openResponse <- select (z, y) %>%
  filter (y != "NA")

print (openResponse)
```
````

Produces this:

[image]

I turned `message` and `waring` off because of all the junk output when loading `dplyr`; you only need `comment=NA` to turn off the `##`.

Comment: Close. @rawr 's response was more what I was looking for. It's going into a report with other charts and tables so I don't necessarily what it to look like just printed code. See my comments above.

Comment: @Greg use if you're using html, use `cat(na.omit(y), sep = '<br />')` and set results='asis'

Comment: @rawr - it's a pdf. I've tried `sep = '//'` and `sep = '//*' ` to no avail.

Comment: Correction - I used '\\' as separators with no luck.